# Query key with value anywhere in object hierarchy in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

In Mongo how can I find all documents that have a given key and value, regardless of where that key appears in the document's key/value hierarchy?

For example the input key `roID` and value `5` would match both:

```
{
  roID: '5'
}
```

and

```
{
  other: {
    roID: '5'
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you can appreciate the inefficiency of your request. You would have to scan each individual document recursively to try and locate that attribute.

Comment: A better question would be explaining your actual use case and why you "think" you need to model this way. That gives people something to base a "real solution" to what you want to do on. But there is no simple way to do this at any depth without traversing the document in JavaScript code. So you likely need a new structure to solve your problem

Comment: @Lix Yes, you're right. I'm sure there's a better way achieving what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in way to do this. You might have to scan each matched document recursively to try and locate that attribute. **Not recommended**. You might want to think about restructuring your data or perhaps manipulating it into a more unified format so that it will be easier (and faster) to query.

---

If your desired key appears in a fixed number of different locations, you could use the `$or` operator to scan all the possibilities.

Taking your sample documents as an example, your query would look something like this:

```
db.data.find( { "$or": [
  { "roID": 5 },
  { "other.roID": 5 },
  { "foo.bar.roID": 5 },
  { any other possbile locations of roID },
  ...
] } )
```

Comment: Yep, the fixed locations route makes more sense. I think I was hoping for a built in method out of laziness.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of documents in collection is not so large, then it can be done by this:

```
db.system.js.save({_id:"keyValueExisted", value: function (key, value) {
    function findme(obj) {
        for (var x in obj) {
            var v = obj[x];
            if (x == key && v == value) {
                return true;
            } else if (v instanceof Object) {
                if (findme(v)) return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    return findme(this);
}});

var param = ['roID', '5'];
db.c.find({$where: "keyValueExisted.apply(this, " + tojsononeline(param) + ");"});
```